# Can the swagger editor online take a YAML url as input through the address bar?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I want to access https://editor.swagger.io/ but need the YAML file to be preloaded based on a URL parameter.

So if I want to view  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml, I should be able to provide this as an input to swagger editor accessible over the internet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, Swagger Editor supports the `url` parameter:

https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml

Note that to load OpenAPI files from GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket/etc., you need to specify the "raw" file link.

Also, for this to work, the server where the YAML/JSON file is hosted must use HTTPS and [support CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) (i.e. allow cross-domain calls from `editor.swagger.io`).

Comment: Is this API for editor.swagger.io documented somewhere?

Comment: @BenMares I think Swagger Editor uses the same config parameters as Swagger UI https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md