# Best way how to publish OpenAPI document on GitHub (readme.md)?

Tags: github, openapi, swagger-editor

I have a project hosted on GitHub. To document the API I am using the OpenAPI spec. Now I want to add a link on `readme.md` (on GitHub) that refers my visitors to the OpenAPI document for good user experience.

Far as I see I have two solutions:

- http://editor.swagger.io/?raw=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/file.yaml
- https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/(username)/(api-name)/(api-version)

Both approaches are working, but they both open with an editor on left side that shows the content of YAML file and is, IMHO, wasting a significant screen space. Not really what I want. Is there an option to display the OpenAPI document without editor opened? Just similiar what is done for https://petstore.swagger.io/ which comes without editor opened.

Or ... is there maybe an option available to display the OpenAPI document on GitHub directly?

Thanks, Christoph

Comment: This question may be better suited for another stack exchange site, though I am not sure which one (maybe seasoned SE vets could help out here?)

Comment: Related: [Can the online Swagger Editor take a YAML URL as input through the address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52975434/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use SwaggerHub, replace `/apis/` with `/apis-docs/` in the URL to view just the API docs without the editor part. For example:

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/swagger-hub/registry-api/1.0.47

Or if your OpenAPI definition is hosted elsewhere (e.g. on GitHub), you can use
https://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://path/to/file.yaml

to load it into the public Swagger UI demo. Swagger UI renders API docs without the editor part.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I have looked for!